# C++ macro without spaces

Tags: c++, macros, space, comments

I need a macro to expand to a c++ comment, is that possible?

I've got this:

```
#define SLASH(x,y) x y
#define OUT SLASH(/,/)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  OUT << "text";
  return 0;
}
```

And need to expand to this:

```
{
  // << "text";
  return 0;
}
```

I've also tried this:

```
#define SLASH(x) /x
#define OUT SLASH(/)
```

But the result is still the same:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  / / << "text";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do exactly ? Why do you need this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others mentioned there is no guaranteed way to define the kind of macro you are looking for. Other ways to achieve results that are similar to what you seem to be trying to achieve are wrapping your output statement in a conditional block or define a custom output stream that just discarded all output. The two approaches may even be combined so that behaviour could be switched by changing a single macro definition.

Comment: Thanks for a hint :). I did it like this: #define OUT if(0) qDebug()

Comment: That's going to break in typical macro fashion. Consider "if (x) OUT << "test passed"; else exit(0);" . This is now always going to exit if the test passes instead of printing something.

Comment: You can fix that in a 'clever' way by doing "#define OUT if(1) true; else qDebug()". Not sure it'll be reliable or anything but at least you've gotten rid of the dangling else.

Answer (score 5):

No it's not possible because in C++ comments are removed before macros are expanded.

(See 2.1 of the standard, comment removal happens in phase 3, macro expansion in phase 4.)

Answer (score 2):

What about replacing it with a function object that does nothing instead?

```
static class NullOutput { 
public:
    template <typename T> 
    const NullOutput &operator<<(T arg) const { 
        return *this; 
    }
} NullOutputObj;

#define OUT NullOutputObj
```

The net result is that the object is removed from the code and replaced by inlined template expansions, that are then optimized out as they do nothing. Result is absolutely no code overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Comments are removed from the source code before the preprocessor runs. So you cannot do this.

Comment: Also, if you concatenate two / / during pre-processing they won't be romoved before because it's not really a comment.

Answer (score 0):

an alternate to what you want to achieve would be this :

http://donjaffer.blogspot.in/2012/09/dprintf-debug-macro-in-c.html

```
#define DEBUG   // comment if you do not want the debug statments to appear.

#ifdef DEBUG
#define DPRINTF(fmt, ...) \
    do { printf("my_file: " fmt, ## __VA_ARGS__); } while (0)
#else
#define DPRINTF(fmt, ...) \
    do { } while (0)
#endif
```

wherever you are trying to print the statements, instead of COUT << you can use

```
DPRINTF("Your text here\n");
```